# VS 2010 mkdir error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs, tfsbuild

Trying to run a TFS build in Visual Studio 2010 and receiving the following error message:

[Build path]\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj (470): The command "if not exist \[Build server]\[Build path]\sources mkdir \[Build server]\[Build path]\sources" exited with code 1.

The build log shows the following:

Task "Exec" (TaskId:14)
if not exist \[Build server]\[Build path]\sources mkdir \[Build server][Build path]\sources (TaskId:14)
Access is denied. (TaskId:14)

The service account the builds and build servers are running under has full rights to all directories that are being written to. Furthermore, it is an account that is currently running builds successfully in another TFS environment.
**Is there anywhere else that requires permissions to be set or altered?**

Thanks in advance for any tips or advice!

Comment: Are you missing quotes?

Comment: The command is part of an auto-generated script that builds the project. The script has not been altered in any way, and has run successfully in the other environment. The build is queued through VS 2010, and the error is displayed in the build output window.

Comment: Does the account running the build service has write permissions on that build path?

Comment: Yes, the service account has full rights to the top level directory of the build path, as well as all subfolders and files.

Comment: Is the `sources` folder marked read-only?

Comment: @KMoraz The sources folder does not exist yet, as this is the first time the project is being built in the new environment. However, I have also tried manually creating the sources folder, but the issue persists.

Comment: Try to restart the build service and browse the event viewer for detailed errors.